# How to add extra columns to wp_posts table in Wordpress?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, post, select

Is it possible to add extra columns in WordPress Posts table and then use select query?

How will the select query be?

Comment: Possible? Yes, it's possible but I'm curious as to why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend wp post meta. See the links below.

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/meta/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

```html
# Set post meta
$ wp post meta set 123 _wp_page_template about.php
Success: Updated custom field '_wp_page_template'.

# Get post meta
$ wp post meta get 123 _wp_page_template
about.php

# Update post meta
$ wp post meta update 123 _wp_page_template contact.php
Success: Updated custom field '_wp_page_template'.

# Delete post meta
$ wp post meta delete 123 _wp_page_template
Success: Deleted custom field.
```

Regards.
Ed.

Comment: This is the correct approach; WordPress already provides meta tables for you to store whatever extra data is needed for all types of record, one don't need to modify the database schema.